# postgresql, добавление пары "ключ" - "значение" при переборе json

Tags: postgresql

Есть следующий json в переменной

```
vars = '[
{"field_oid":"a1","field_type":"string","field_value":"Заголовок"}, 
{"field_oid":"b2","field_type":"editor","field_value":"Текст"}, 
{"field_oid":"c3","field_type":"checkbox","field_value":"{\"0\": {\"active\":\"1\",\"field_value\":\"1\"}, \"1\":{\"active\":\"0\",\"field_value\":\"2\"} }"}  ]';
```

я перебираю его с помощью конструкции

```
FOR i IN 0..(json_array_length(vars) - 1) 
LOOP
-- если тип checkbox, то
    IF vars->i->>'field_type' = 'checkbox' 
    THEN
    -- jsonb_insert делает добавление пары "ключ" : "значение" в field_value
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Если значение поля "field_type" равняется "checkbox", то вопрос: как правильно оформить синтаксис jsonb_insert, чтобы добавить в значение ключа field_value->>'0', ->>'1', ->> n дополнительную пару "new_name" : "new_value", дабы получился результат вида

```
field_value: {"0": {"active":"1", "field_value":"1", "new_name":"new_value"}, "1": {"active":"1", "field_value":"2", "new_name":"new_value"}}
```

Comment: В чём изначальная задача?  Зачем вы делаете это внутри _PL/PgSQL_?  Если вам нужно просто обновить, почему не воспользоваться обычным `UPDATE`?

Comment: Я не понимаю, как добавить в значение field_value для типа checkbox дополнительные пары ключ-значение в цикле. Мой листинг - это часть функции, полностью ее нет смысла приводить, не в ней дело. vars - это результат некой выборки, который нужно модифицировать перед возвратом из функции